# Exception DateTime OleDbParameter

Tags: visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures, parameters, sql-server-2000, oledb

I’m using Visual Studio 2010. Within the project we add a DataSet, inside it; we have a Query Table Adapter to do all the queries to a SQL Server 2000 Data Base. One of the queries is formed using a Stored Procedure that receives four parameters. One of the parameters is a DateTime data type. Although we have check many times, we are receiving an unexpected exception:

```
Provider encountered an error while sending command parameter[0] '' value and stopped processing.
Conversion failed for command parameter[1] '' because the data value overflowed the type used by the provider.
Provider encountered an error while sending command parameter[2] '' value and stopped processing.
Provider encountered an error while sending command parameter[3] '' value and stopped processing.
Provider encountered an error while sending command parameter[4] '' value and stopped processing.
```

Working around this, if we delete the DateTime parameter of the Store Procedure, the query executes successfully otherwise we get the exception mentioned before.

We notice that the DateTime parameter has the property set as follows:

```
DbType: DateTime
ProviderType: DBTimeStamp
```

Any approach trying to accomplish the execution of the Query will be greatly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

When I received this error, I had to change my date parameter to tell what the data type was.

Old Way

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("TDate", DateTime.Now));
```

New Way

```
OleDbParameter dateParam = new OleDbParameter("TDate", OleDbType.Date);
dateParam.Value = DateTime.Now;
cmd.Parameters.Add(dateParam);
```